Script to Carry Out Action at Set Time
I wrote the script below to carry out an action at the time set in the entry widget. It is started by the clicking on the button. Once the current time is equal to that set on the timer, an action is run and the thread is closed. I want to used as little resources as possible. Can anyone suggest changes to make this timer as reliable and efficient as possible?
#!/usr/bin/python3.9

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time

from datetime import datetime
from threading import Event
from threading import Thread

timer_flag = False

class Timer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, set_time):
        super().__init__()

        self.set_time = set_time

        self.event = Event()

    def run(self):
            
        while True:

            time_now= datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')

            if time_now == self.set_time:

                frame.run_this_action()
                
                self.event.set()
                    
            if self.event.is_set():
                print('The thread was stopped')

                break

            time.sleep(1)

    
    def halt(self, timeout=None):

        print ("THREAD QUIT")
      
        self.event.set()
        
        Thread.join(self, timeout)


class MainFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        self.button=tk.Button(text='OFF', bg='red', bd=8, activebackground="yellow", 
            height=6, width=12, relief="raised", command=self.toggle, font='ubuntu 16')
        
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=200, pady=100)


        self.entry_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry_var.set('00:00')
        self.entry=tk.Entry(textvariable=self.entry_var, font="ubuntu 16",
            justify='center', foreground='red', insertontime=0)
        self.entry.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=tk.W, ipady=10)
        

    def toggle(self):

        if self.button.config('relief')[-1] == 'sunken':
            self.button.config(relief='raised', text="OFF", bg='red', 
                font='ubuntu 16')
            self.end()

        else:
            self.button.config(relief="sunken", text="ON", bg="green",
                font='ubuntu 16')
            self.start()


    ## start timer thread
    def start(self):

        global timer_flag
        timer_flag = False

        set_time= self.entry.get()

        timer_thread=Timer(set_time)
        timer_thread.start()

        self.timer_monitor(timer_thread)
        
        self.stop_(timer_thread)


    ## for timer thread
    def timer_monitor(self, thread):
        
        if thread.is_alive():
            
            #check the thread every 100ms
            self.after(100,lambda:self.timer_monitor(thread))
            
        else:
            print ("thread is stopped")
            
            self.button.config(relief='raised', text="OFF", bg='red',
                font='ubuntu 16')


    def stop_(self, thread):

        if timer_flag == False:
            
            #check the thread every 100ms
            self.after(100,lambda:self.stop_(thread))
        else:
            thread.halt()
            print("QUIT")
            

    def end(self):
        
        global timer_flag
        
        timer_flag = True

        print ("timer flag is", timer_flag)


    def run_this_action(self):
        print ("the action has been run")


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 

        self.geometry("1200x550") # air
        #self.resizable(False, False)
        self.title('coffee timer v5') 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    frame=MainFrame(app)
    app.mainloop()


It worked for me. Using Python 3.12.6. the action has been run
The thread was stopped
thread is stopped
the action has been run
The thread was stopped
thread is stopped

I suggest you update Python 3.12.6
